# Why does Microsoft Word force-change the font to Calibri when typing in Polytonic Greek?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I am using the Microsoft Office 2016 Beta Preview (Microsoft Word 15.13.1) on OS X Yosemite (10.10.5), but as far as I can recall, this issue has been present for a long time.

I have my Normal.dotm set up so that the `Normal` paragraph style uses Minion, which [fully supports the Greek Extended range](http://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/minion/regular). This works fine in general: when opening a new document, the default font is Minion.

When I type something in Modern Greek (i.e., Greek letters with only acute accents), the font remains Minion with no problems.

However, when I type more or less anything from the Greek Extended range (vowels with circumflex accents like ᾶῶῆ and/or rough or smooth breathing marks like ἀἁἄἅἆἇ, etc.), Word stubbornly—and **extremely** annoyingly—insists on immediately switching the font to Calibri, despite the fact that Minion contains the necessary glyphs.<sup>1</sup> I then have to manually reapply the relevant paragraph style for every paragraph that happens to have such a glyph in it for it to display properly in Minion.

Why does this happen? Precisely which range of characters provokes this infuriating behaviour? And most importantly, **is there any way to prevent it from happening?**

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> It doesn’t happen with *all* these characters. Grave accents usually go through just fine, and at least some vowels with only a breathing mark also go through fine; but circumflexes nearly always breaks it, and an iota subscript is sure to do so.</sup>

Comment: just shooting in the dark, is the TTF instead of OTF version of Minion installed? Or maybe it's the other way around. Word wants TTF instead.